# Cannot find under-development app under My Apps

Tags: bigcommerce

I have created a trial store and a new app. I am trying to install the app for my store but I cannot find it listed under `My Apps`....

What do I need to test my app?

Answer (score 1):

When you go to `My Apps` in your store's control panel you should see a tab for `My Draft Apps` as pictured here.

[Store Control Panel Screenshot](http://grab.by/KtZe)

Any apps with a status of "Draft" that are shown in the `My Apps` section of the *developer portal* should show up under that `My Draft Apps` tab in the store *control panel*.

[Developer Portal Screenshot](http://grab.by/KtZM)